# Atomic property block or cancel a particular thread request for accessing variable when variable is already used by another thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Suppose there is a string named - aString

```
@property (atomic, retain) NSString *aString;
```

So now suppose  Thread A is working with aString, at that time Thread B is trying to access aString. I know since aString property is atomic, Thread B won't be able to access it but my question is whether Thread B's access request is cancelled or it's request will execute after Thread A finish it's execution.

Thanks for you reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread B will wait untill thread A finished to read the property content.

When you access a property is nothing else that call the getter method of the property, and if is atomic means that the getter method access is protected by a mutex, so untill the getter method doesn't return all the other thread trying to access the property are waiting.

If you owerwrite the getter/setter of the property you are responsable to implement the thread synchronization into the methods body otherwise the property will be no longer atomic

Comment: Hi Manu, thanks. So the answer is - access request by other thread will remain pending rather than cancelled.